# How to include "None" in lte/gte comparisons?

Tags: django

I've got this complex filtering mechanism...

```
d = copy(request.GET)
d.setdefault('sort_by', 'created')
d.setdefault('sort_dir', 'desc')
form = FilterShipmentForm(d)
filter = {
    'status': ShipmentStatuses.ACTIVE
}
exclude = {}
if not request.user.is_staff:
    filter['user__is_staff'] = False

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    exclude['user__blocked_by__blocked'] = request.user

if form.is_valid():
    d = form.cleaned_data
    if d.get('pickup_city'): filter['pickup_address__city__icontains'] = d['pickup_city']
    if d.get('dropoff_city'): filter['dropoff_address__city__icontains'] = d['dropoff_city']
    if d.get('pickup_province'): filter['pickup_address__province__exact'] = d['pickup_province']
    if d.get('dropoff_province'): filter['dropoff_address__province__exact'] = d['dropoff_province']
    if d.get('pickup_country'): filter['pickup_address__country__exact'] = d['pickup_country']
    if d.get('dropoff_country'): filter['dropoff_address__country__exact'] = d['dropoff_country']
    if d.get('min_price'): filter['target_price__gte'] = d['min_price']
    if d.get('max_price'): filter['target_price__lte'] = d['max_price']
    if d.get('min_distance'): filter['distance__gte'] = d['min_distance'] * 1000
    if d.get('max_distance'): filter['distance__lte'] = d['max_distance'] * 1000
    if d.get('available_on'): # <--- RELEVANT BIT HERE ---
        filter['pickup_earliest__lte'] = d['available_on'] # basically I want "lte OR none"
        filter['pickup_latest__gte'] = d['available_on']
    if d.get('shipper'): filter['user__username__iexact'] = d['shipper']

order = ife(d['sort_dir'] == 'desc', '-') + d['sort_by']

shipments = Shipment.objects.filter(**filter).exclude(**exclude).order_by(order) \
    .annotate(num_bids=Count('bids'), min_bid=Min('bids__amount'), max_bid=Max('bids__amount'))
```

And now my client tells me he wants pickup/drop-off dates to be 'flexible' as an option. So I've updated the DB to allow dates to be NULL for this purpose, but now the "available for pickup on" filter won't work as expected. It should include NULL/None dates. Is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most database engines don't like relational comparisons with `NULL` values. Use `<field>__isnull` to explicitly check if a value is `NULL` in the database, but you'll need to use [`Q` objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to `OR` the conditions together.

Comment: Bummer... I was hoping I could avoid Q objects, that function is nasty enough as is. What should I do then? Make `filter` a list instead of a dict, and push Q objects onto it instead, then if I do `Shipment.objects.filter(*filter)` it should work, right?

Comment: Correct. or you could `reduce()` it with `operator.and_` instead.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know about `operator.and_`, but better yet, I can forget the list and just do `filter &=` everywhere to append to Q-object directly.

Comment: This conversation is interesting and the methods you are discussing would be useful to me. Would you mind explaining these techniques further?

Answer (score 17):

Flip the logic and use `exclude()`. What you really want to do is exclude any data that specifies a date that doesn't fit. If `pickup_latest` and `pickup_earliest` are `NULL` it shouldn't match the exclude query and wont be removed. Eg

```
exclude['pickup_latest__lt'] = d['available_on']
exclude['pickup_earliest__gt'] = d['available_on']
```

Comment: Oh...right! Of course! :) This would have been the easiest solution, but I already went ahead with Q-objects.

Comment: brilliant, just brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that's actually a django-specific question. Variable 'd' is a python dictionary, no? If so, you can use this:

`filter['pickup_latest__gte'] = d.get('available_on', None)`

Comment: It's very django specific. The filter keys correlate to Django's ORM.